# ggplot with different font family fails to save to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf, fonts, ggsave

I've seen a lot of suggestions but to my frustration I can't seem to save a simple pdf plot using a different font in ggplot2. I am using ggplot version 3.3.5 in R version
4.1.3 from within Rstudio 2022.07.1 on a mac.

All I use to change the font in my ggplot code is `theme(text = element_text(family = "AppleGothic")`.

It looks fine from within Rstudio. But when I export to pdf, the resulting file is completely blank. Not just the text, but everything. If I try instead
`ggsave("/path/", fig, device = 'pdf')` I get the error message

`error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :  failed to find or load PDF CID font`

I would greatly appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try `ggsave("/path/", fig, device = cairo_pdf)`. I got the same issue on Jupyter notebook and this resolve it.